# Is the word "Einstein" a verb?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, verbing

I know that a lot of people use the word "Einstein" to convey someone as a genius, but I was wondering if Einstein, as a verb, is an official term.

Comment: In the sense that "he's such an Einstein!" or "he Einsteined that physics exam!"?

Comment: Also, assuming a word is an "official term" if it's in the dictionary, then [Einstein is not a verb](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Einstein).

Comment: Chaos, seeing as several of your most recent questions have been closed, I strongly suggest that you do even a quick internet search before posting.

Comment: It's worth noting that when we do call someone "Einstein," very often we're being sarcastic. For example, if someone answers a question incorrectly at school, another student might say, "Nice job, Einstein," in a sarcastic tone of voice.

Comment: The question is already dead, but... I think it was referring to usage of "Einstein" like "MacGyver."

Comment: @Dave: But to "Einstein something" isn't officially accepted, anyway

Comment: @simchona - "To Einstein" is not an officially or unofficially accepted verb. I've never heard it used, possibly due it its sarcastic usage as a noun. My comment was simply to address the preceding comments dealing with Einstein as a noun, rather than a verb (as requested).

Comment: There is no word in the English language that cannot be verbed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an official word in dictionaries unless (in lowercase) as a unit of [radiant energy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Einstein).  I've very infrequently heard it used informally to mean *genius*, but it's not officially recognized.

Though I did find one thing interesting about this - I googled for "einsteined" (as a verb), and the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=einsteined) has an interesting definition:

> Verb. the act of being called out on acting or doing something lame/dumb.
>
> *Guy #1: OK, I'm going to go home and watch a movie with my mom. See all you later!*
>
> *Guy #2: Wow, you watch movies with your mom? That's so lame.*
>
> *Guy #3: (to Guy#1)You just got einsteined, man.*

I've never seen/heard this, but it just might be best to keep in mind in case you ever decide to use it.

Comment: @simchona: Check out the edit.

Comment: Well, I guess I was making up some logical things. The fact that it's in UD and not even MW leads me to heartily support your conclusion.

Comment: +1 For finding Urban Dictionary and still saying it's not officially recognized

Comment: You didn't google for it, you Googled for it. :)