# To "Macgyver" or to "macgyver"?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, verbing

I recently came across this usage “we Macgyver…” and the use of the upper case  caught my attention.  I googled the word to see if it is mentioned in the dictionary; Wiktionary gave me this result, for instance:

> **[Macgyver](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/MacGyver#Verb)** Verb
>
> MacGyver (third-person singular simple present **MacGyvers**, present participle **MacGyvering**, simple past and past participle **MacGyvered**)
>
> 1. (intransitive) To assemble or repair something by ingenious improvisation, using everyday items that would not usually be used for the purpose.
>
>    - *Our car broke down and we didn't have any tools but Jim **MacGyvered** it with some toenail clippers and we were able to limp to the service station.*
>    - *No place to climb? MacGyver your own set-up in a power rack for rope pull-ups or rows.*

I googled the word *google* as well, here is the result:

> **[google](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/google#Verb)** Verb
>
> **google** (third-person singular simple present **googles**, present participle **googling**, simple past and past participle **googled**)
>     1. (intransitive, cricket) To deliver googlies.
>     2. (intransitive, cricket) To move as a ball in a googly.

Now,  both words are proper nouns, but “google” is not capitalised whereas “Macgyver” is.

Why?

Comment: Related: [When “Skyping” is used as a verb, should it be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79038/when-skyping-is-used-as-a-verb-should-it-be-capitalized)

Comment: Checking out the etymology of *Macgyver* should clarify. (Note the capitalization here.)

Comment: You need to wait a few years before *Macgyver* becomes more widely used when it might no longer need to be capitalized: cf. *vulcanization*.

Comment: @Kris but which is older "Macgyver" or "Google"?

Comment: Firstly, I think the comparison with *Google* is incorrect -- *Google* was not a proper noun -- it was formed from 'gogol' which meant a large, large number (like *zillion*). Furthermore, *Google* as a word is far widely used than *Macgyver*.

Comment: @RegDwighт The link perfectly answered my question. Thx

Comment: The comparison with google/Google is irrelevant because the cricket term is not derived from the company name.

Comment: McGyver is older than Google.

Comment: The question is not which of "Macgyver" or "Google" is older, but which is more widely used.

Comment: I think part of the difference is that when you 'MacGyver' something, you are acting like or doing something as it might be done *by* MacGyver (you're referencing the character by name), you can google something and not be making a reference to the company Google (especially given the genericization of 'Google' as search)

Comment: Also see   [Is the word “Einstein” a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/36860),

Comment: If you don't like to see the verb MacGyver capitalized perhaps you should boycott it or if your feelings run stronger you could guillotine it.

Comment: @AllInOne Great pun.

Answer (score 1):

MacGyver uses capitals because it's taken from the TV show from which the term comes. In the TV show the name is spelt **M**ac**G**yver, because it is the lead characters last name which is of Scottish decent, hence the M and G should always be capitals. Any time you see the word used with only an uppercase M you can assume it is incorrect.

Information obtained from the [MacGyver Online](http://www.macgyveronline.com) resource and information site.